# javascript encode text by escaping forward slash using backward slash

Tags: javascript, string, base64, decode, encode

I have a text with which is a base 64 string and I wanted to encode that base64 code by escaping special character `/` using `\/` .

I have used `encodeURIComponent` and   `str.replace(/\//g, '\\/');`
but it would get the string with the `\/`

if I illustrate more with an example

**base64string**

```
"samplebase64/samplebase64/samplebase64/samplebase64+samplebase64"
```

I need this to convert into

**base64encodedstring**

```
"samplebase64\/samplebase64\/samplebase64\/samplebase64+samplebase64"
```

Comment: Your second string is `===` to your first string, did you mean `"samplebase64\\/sample...`? (to have a single backslash indicate a single literal backslash, use `String.raw`)

Comment: no i just created a variable to show that which strings i need to be converted.

Comment: Ok, but the strings you listed are the same - probably best to clarify that the second string contains literal backslashes (rather than unnecessary escape characters)

Comment: its not the same 1st string is with only "/" second string is with "\/" thats what i need to have

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the "/" characters in your base 64 string with "%2F" or use the `encodeURIComponent` with your base64 strings with "/". Note that if you have multiple Base64 strings to be included in a structured URL, you will have to use `encodeURIComponent` on them seperately.

```
var myOrderedBase64Array = ['base/641', base/642];    

var uri = myOrderedBase64Array.map(function(item){

   return encodeURIComponent(item);
}).join('/');
```

Comment: what i need is not to change it into "%2F" i need to put "\/" in the string where i want to save this as a json. cause im reading this from another java code. so to make it compatibility i need to change it to "\/" not "%2F"